# Random Numbers to a Sum value in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have list of numbers from Row 1 to Row 12 say in Column A and I need to have the number of each row distributed in to four different columns (Column B, C, D, E) in Matlab so that:
(i) the sum of values shown in columns B, C, D, E is equal to the value of Column A.
(ii) The values shall only be whole numbers.
(iii) Columns B, C, D, E have maximum limit of 10, 10, 5 and 5 respectively.
(iv) Columns B, C, D, E have minimum limit of 5, 5, 3, 3 respectively.

That is the values generated in these columns should be with in these maximum limit values.

Example:
| A | B | C | D |

| 17 | 6 | 5 | 3 | 3 |

Any way to pick values from Column A and then get the values in different columns (B,C,D,E) so that the sum is equal to A for each row?

I tried like this but it still lacks the exact target. Some of the issues are mentioned after coding:

```
clear all
while true
 A=randi([3 5],12,4);
     if((sum(A,2)>=16) | (sum(A,2)<=30));
   break;
end
end

disp(A);
disp(sum(A,2));
```

All the values generated are random, however they are between 16 and 30. But the lowest value limit I can not sort out how to do for BCDE? And if I already have a data of column A then how can I make the BCDE values equal to that sum for each row?

Comment: Can the numbers be negative (or 0)? If so, what is the lowest value they can obtain (is it -10, -10, -5, -5)? If not, how can you make 2 or 3 by adding together 4 positive numbers?

Comment: The values in all columns can only be positive and whole numbers. The values of column A shall be with in 16 (lowest) and 30 (highest). Column BCDE will be a summation equal to the corresponding value of column A in each row. Keeping in view the maximum limitation of each BCDE column.

Comment: Lowest value of column BCDE will be 5,5,3,3 whereas the highest is 10,10,5,5 respectively.

Comment: You should edit the question with this new information! So B and C are 5-10 and D and E are 3,4 or 5? How random do you need this to be? Uniform or just random in the sense that it's unpredictable?

Comment: I have edited the question. As long as the numbers are in range (lower and upper limit) and getting equal to the value of column A in each of the 12 rows, it will be fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fast and deterministic approach without using loops. The idea is to first split the number `A` into two halves `L`, `R`. The condition for both `L` and `R` is they lie between `[8 15]`. The function `randSplit(x, lo, hi)` will do that.

Choose `L = B + D` and `R = C + E`. Now the remaining part is two split `L` into `[B, D]` and split `R` into `[C, E]`; the function `randSplit(x, lo, hi, LO, HI)` will do that. The condition in this case is `B`, `C` both lie between `[5 10]` and `D`, `E` both lie between `[3 5]`.

This method is fast as it calls `randi` exactly 3 times per row of the output matrix.

```
A = randi([16 30], 12,1);
mat = zeros(12,4);
for i = 1:12   
    [L, R] = randSplit(A(i), 8, 15); % L = B + D, R = C + E
    [B, D] = randSplit(L, 3, 5, 5, 10);
    [C, E] = randSplit(R, 3, 5, 5, 10);
    mat(i,:) = [B C D E];
end

function [a, b] = randSplit(x, lo, hi, LO, HI)
    if nargin == 3
        a = randi([max(lo,x-hi) min(hi,x-lo)]);
        b = x - a;
    elseif nargin == 5
        a = randi([max(LO,x-hi) min(HI,x-lo)]);
        b = x - a;
    end
end
```

Sample output:

```
[A mat] =
    29    10    10     5     4
    21     8     5     5     3
    23    10     5     5     3
    21     5     9     4     3
    17     5     6     3     3
    27     8     9     5     5
    19     8     5     3     3
    30    10    10     5     5
    17     5     6     3     3
    27    10     9     5     3
    18     5     6     3     4
    25     9    10     3     3
```

Comment: How may I use the values of column A in your coding from the data that I already have? So that the BCDE will then sum up to the values of column A that I assigned in A?

Comment: Currently we are generating values in all columns randomly. If possible I would like to generate only BCDE randomly with respect to A (where values in A are entered or imported from the data).

Comment: @Jack -- Sure, no problem, I pulled `A` outside the loop and created only the BCDE matrix. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you do this with a simple loop:

```
M = [0,0,0,0];  % A, B, C, D
For each A
    While sum(M) is not A
        M(A) = [(2 random numbers 5-10), (2 random numbers 3-5)]
    end
end
```

Use `randi` to get the random numbers.

This is not optimal for large numbers/lists but I'm fairly sure will be fast enough for the numbers you work with unless you do this millions of times.

I'll leave implementing this in MATLAB to you as an exercise. :) Shout out if you get stuck.

---

**Update:**

This is quick and dirty, but it works :) It uses 130 ms on average on [tio.run](https://tio.run/#octave).

```
A = 15+randi(15,12,1);
BCDE = zeros(numel(A),4);
temp = [0, 0, 0, 0];
for ii = 1:numel(A)
    temp = [4+randi(6,1,2), 2+randi(3,1,2)];
    while sum(temp) ~= A(ii)
        temp = [4+randi(6,1,2), 2+randi(3,1,2)];
    end
    BCDE(ii,:) = temp;
end
[A, BCDE]

ans = 
   16    5    5    3    3
   18    5    5    4    4
   18    5    6    4    3
   29   10   10    5    4
   24    6   10    3    5
   27   10    9    4    4
   18    5    6    3    4
   23    5   10    5    3
   27    9    8    5    5
   24    7    9    3    5
   28   10   10    3    5
   20    9    5    3    3
```

Comment: i have edit the question with the coding that I used using randi

Comment: Good attempt :) Edited my answer. Not pretty, but it works.

Comment: Thank you for the efforts, it is working fine. Just one last thing that since I already have the result of Column A (in excel file) and I can copy them to matlab as well or make matlab read the data from the excel file Column A and save it in variable A as following:

A=xlsread('data.xlsx','A:A');

How can I get the values of this A into your coding and keeping other criteria same as before?